# How can I implement Applicative on my list, modelling non-determinism?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I was practicing Functor / Applicative Functors + Monads in Haskell when I came across [this assignment](https://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/puh-2015-ha6.pdf):

> 4) You have seen how a Monad instance can be used to handle things that can
>   fail. Another use case for a Monad is dealing with non-determinism. The simplest
>   way to model non-deterministic computation is using a list. Think of the list as
>   holding all possible results of some computation. When you use the well known map
>   function, the function you are applying produces the outputs for all the possible
>   inputs. [...]
>
> Define your list type like so:
>
> ```
> data MyList a = Cons a (MyList a) | Nil deriving Show
> ```
>
> (a) Make your list an instance of Functor.
>   (b) Make your list an instance of Applicative.
>   (c) Make your list an instance of Monad.

I am having some trouble with it. This is my current solution:

```
instance Functor MyList where
    fmap f (Nil) = Nil
    fmap f (Cons item other) = (Cons (f item) (fmap f other))

instance Applicative MyList where
    pure item = (Cons item Nil)
    Nil <*> _ = Nil
    _ <*> Nil = Nil
    (Cons f item) <*> something = (fmap f something) ++ (item <*> something)
```

Problem is with `(item <*> something)`. With a list the `++` operator would have made this possible but I even made a function that had a `++` operator but this method still does not work. How can I implement the Applicative for this type?

This is my ++ implementation:

```
(++) :: (MyList a) -> a -> (MyList a)
(++) Nil item = (Cons item Nil)
(++) (Cons val other) item = (Cons val (other ++ item))
```

This is the error I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> b’
            with actual type ‘MyList (a -> b)’
Relevant bindings include
  something :: MyList a (bound at Assignment_6.hs:13:23)
  item :: MyList (a -> b) (bound at Assignment_6.hs:13:13)
  f :: a -> b (bound at Assignment_6.hs:13:11)
  (<*>) :: MyList (a -> b) -> MyList a -> MyList b
    (bound at Assignment_6.hs:11:5)
In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘item’
In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
  ‘(fmap f something) ++ item’
```

Comment: It _should_ actually work with a custom `++` operator (which BTW would best be realised [as a `Monoid` instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:-60--62-)). What error are you getting?

Comment: If you don't get a compiler error, what is your expected behaviour, and what behaviour do you observe?

Comment: (++) :: (MyList a) -> a -> (MyList a)
(++) Nil item = (Cons item Nil)
(++) (Cons val other) item = (Cons val (other ++ item))

(This is my custom ++ operator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare the following two types:

```
(Prelude.++) :: []     a -> [] a -> []     a
(George.++)  :: MyList a ->    a -> MyList a
```

Can you spot the problem?

Comment: It should be:

(Prelude.++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a],

(George.++) :: (MyList a) -> (MyList a) -> (MyList a)

And I think I got it. Let me try and comment back. Thanks. :)